# Javazoom MP3 Player does not work outside of Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, mp3

i'am using the Player class from javazoom (javazoom.jl.player.Player) to play mp3 files. From within my Netbeans IDE (version 7.4), sounds are played successfully. But as soon i start my program from outside the IDE, sounds are not played anymore!

Does anyone know what the reason could be?

PS: Both, Netbeans IDE and Java environment outside in windows uses the same java framework: Java 1.7.0_40

Thank you

Comment: It seems, that it depends on the length of the mp3 track. Short mp3 tracks (< 1 sec) are only played within the IDE but outside the IDE the duration seems to be too short... If the track is several seconds in length, it works also outside the IDE... However, i don't really know what the reasons for this behaviour is...

Comment: My telepathic abilities are currently a little dull; but from what I can sniff out from your computer you did something wrong- Thats about as good for an answer you can expect given the info you provided in your question.

Comment: My telepathic abilities are also poor, but my guess is you are not waiting for the player to tell you it has finished playing.

Comment: Hi, guys, i'am sorry but it's _really_ hard to describe all things that might cause this problem... Anyway: even if wait in a while loop until the player is finished (while(!player.isComplete()) it does not work OUTSIDE the IDE for short mp3 files...

Answer (score 0):

i guess i have solved it now with two steps:

1.) I used the MP3 SPI from http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/sources.html to play sounds

2.) I have a Netbeans maven project and i use filtering in case of resources, so i have to exclude the folder where sounds are saved, otherwise the sound files become corrupted when Netbeans is copying files to target folder and are not recognized as mp3 files anymore:

```
<resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <targetPath>../resources</targetPath>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>data/sounds/**</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <targetPath>../resources</targetPath>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>data/sounds/**</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

Now, even short mp3 files works as expected!